# If $x+y=8$ then find the minimum value of $(1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y})$ using AGM inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

As title says find the minimum value of  $(1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y})$when given that $x+y=8$ using AGM inequality including Arithmetic Mean, Geometric Mean, and Harmonic Mean.

Comment: shouldn't the minimum value be 1. I checked with WolframAlpha it is also showing 1 and I am also getting 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Expanding your term we get
$$1+\frac{x+y}{xy}+\frac{1}{xy}=1+\frac{9}{xy}$$
By AM-GM we get

$$\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$$ from here we get

$$1+\frac{9}{xy}\geq \frac{9}{16}+1$$

Comment: thanks a lot for help

Comment: And thank you for the nice problem!

Comment: shouldn't the minimum value be 1.  I checked with WolframAlpha it is also showing 1 and I am also getting 1 Sir can you check your solution and mine solution

Answer (score 1):

Using all three means:
$$(1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y})=1+\color{red}{\frac1x+\frac1y}+\color{blue}{\frac1{xy}}\ge 1+\color{red}{\frac12}+\color{blue}{\frac1{16}}=\frac{25}{16},$$
where:
$$\text{AM-HM:} \ \ \frac{x+y}{2}\ge \frac{2}{\frac1x+\frac1y} \iff \frac1x+\frac1y\ge \frac4{x+y}=\frac48=\frac12;\\
\text{AM-GM:} \ \ \frac{x+y}{2}\ge \sqrt{xy} \iff \frac{1}{xy}\ge \left(\frac{2}{x+y}\right)^2=\left(\frac{2}{8}\right)^2=\frac1{16}.$$
Equality occurs for $x=y=4$.